# Is there a way to make a program pause for a certain time but still have another piece of code running?

Tags: python, time

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

I want a for loop running while that is happening how do I do that

Comment: use a thread that you start before calling sleep

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: See also, asyncio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use concurrent execution of tasks to achieve what you intend to do,
Have a look at code which helps you clear your understanding of concurrent programming,

```
import time
from concurrent import futures

def busy():
    print("\nRunning in seprate thread")
    print("\nTask started")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\nTask accomplished")

def main():
    executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    executor.submit(busy)

    for i in range(100):
        print("\nRunning in main thread")
        time.sleep(1)

    executor.shutdown() # --> wait for all the tasks to get finished

main()
```

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation